# Interactive way to remove SVG elements from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am generating SVG rectangles via javascript/inline HTML5 and i would like to know if i can attach a closing icon (like this : [https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRV4yho7mQoRWj-wEd8LvvKjs4sMAWSFi9cJu5IxGtWn667ofL10g](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcRV4yho7mQoRWj-wEd8LvvKjs4sMAWSFi9cJu5IxGtWn667ofL10g)) in the top right corner of one rectangle so that when i drag the rectangle, the icon doesnt stay static to that position and always be attached to that rectangle.

My goal is to give the user the chance to remove that rectangle from the page.

If there is an easier way to do this removing thing, feel free to let me know!

Thanks in advance!

---

Drag and drop functions:

```
var selectedElement = 0;
        var currentX = 10;
        var currentY = 10;
        var currentMatrix = 0;

        function selectElement(evt) {

            selectedElement = evt.target;
            currentX = evt.clientX;
            currentY = evt.clientY;
            currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7, -1).split(' ');

            for (var i = 0; i < currentMatrix.length; i++) {
                currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
            }

            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(event)");
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(event)");

        }      

        function deselectElement(evt) {

            if (selectedElement != 0) {

                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");

                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");

                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");

                selectedElement = 0;
            }

        }       


        function moveElement(evt) {

            dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
            dy = evt.clientY - currentY;

            currentMatrix[4] += dx;
            currentMatrix[5] += dy;
            newMatrix = "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")";

            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", newMatrix);

            currentX = evt.clientX;

            currentY = evt.clientY;

        }
```

Creating elements:

```
var g1 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');

                g1.setAttribute('transform', "translate(200,200)");

                rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');
                circle = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');


                    rect.setAttribute('id', "rec1");
                    rect.setAttribute('x', 224);
                    rect.setAttribute('y', 34);
                    rect.setAttribute('width', 188);
                    rect.setAttribute('height', 68);                    
                    rect.setAttribute('class', "draggableOrgUnit");                  
                    rect.setAttribute('transform', "matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)");                    
                    rect.setAttribute('onmousedown', "selectElement(event)");                                      
                    //rect.setAttribute('onmouseup', "drop(event)");

                    circle.setAttribute('id', "c0");
                    circle.setAttribute('cx', "224");
                    circle.setAttribute('cy', "34");
                    circle.setAttribute('r', "5");
                    circle.setAttribute('onclick', "closeMe()");
                    circle.setAttribute('fill', "blue");
```

Output:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <g>
    <rect>
    <circle>
    </g>
    ...
  <g>
</svg>
```

Im only testing this rectangle. Once this works, the others will follow the same logic.

Comment: Show us your HTML/JS code, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place both the rect and your click-to-close element inside a `<g>` element. then to place the rect you would translate the `<g>` to the desired location. Also you could drag/drop the `<g>`, via translate, if desired.

Example below shows a circle as the click-to-close element, placed in the upper-right corner of the rect. Instead of the circle, you could also use an `<image>` element per your example:

```
<g transform="translate(200 200)">
<rect width=50 height=25 fill=red />
<circle onclick=closeMe() r=5 fill=blue cx=43 cy=5 />
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation but when i drag the rectangle, the circle remains at the same place. I've edited my question and put there my drag and drop code and also a summary of the output i get in the browser.

Comment: The only problem that i'm facing right now is not being able to "attach" the circle into the rectangle (or in upper-right) so when i drag it, the circle follows him towards the drop position

Comment: The rect drag function should drag the <g> : e.g. function dragRect(evt){var myG=evt.target.parentNode; myG.setAttribute("transform("+transX+" "+transY+")");}

Comment: Just tried that and worked exactly as i wanted! :) Thanks a lot Francis Hemsher!